# Perl opens file but doesn't read contents

Tags: perl, greatest-common-divisor

My Perl program seems to successfully open the text file I want it to read, but it's not using the information within the text file in the code.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub gcd_iter($$) {
    my ( $u, $v ) = @_;

    while ( $v ) {
        ( $u, $v ) = ( $v, $u % $v );
    }

    return abs( $u );
}

my $gcdcount = 0;
my $filename = "Integers1.txt";

open( my $fh, "<", $filename ) or die( "Can't open file $filename, $!" );

while ( my @integers = <$fh> ) {

    my $value1   = shift( @integers );
    my $value2   = shift( @integers );
    my @trngpair = ( $value1, $value2 );

    if ( gcd_iter( $value1, $value2 ) == 1 ) {
        $gcdcount++;
    }
}

print "$gcdcount\n";

close $fh;
```

The program isn't printing the pair array or the correct gcdcount. I have the program doing something similar 2 other times and the gcdcount is calculated properly, but for this one it's not. The output reads that the gcdcount is 0 every time I run the program. The subroutine for the gcd calculation is farther up in the code.

The input file is normally 2000 lines of randomly generated integers, but the problem can be produced using the following:

```
83
399
2
343
267
120
893
33
```

Comment: Could you [edit] the question to show an example of the `Integers1.txt` format?

Comment: *"The program isn't printing the pair array or the correct gcdcount"* That would be because there is no `print` statement in your code.

Comment: @Borodin, I realize that and I edited it out for clarity. The print gcdcount is included under the minimal example I added later in the post.

Comment: You're asking why your code doesn't print the pair array, and you edit out the `print` call for "clarity"? I can't say I understand your thinking.

Comment: Please add `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` to the top of *every* Perl program you write and fix any resulting errors, especially before asking the whole world to help you with your code.

Comment: I'm not receiving any errors is the issue, I'm receiving 0 for the count because the loop is running only once.

Comment: *Never* use subroutine prototypes unless you're absolutely clear what they do and particularly need that special effect. In this case I'm pretty sure you don't understand Perl prototypes, and have jammed them in there despite pretty much every example of a Perl subroutine on the internet working without them. `sub gcd_iter($$) { ... }` is perfectly good as `sub gcd_iter { ... }`.

Comment: Some better test data would help. The GCD of both 83 & 399 and 2 & 33 is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<$fh>` in list context reads the remainder of the file and evaluates to a scalar for each line.

That means `my @integers = <$fh>;` reads the remainder of the file the first time it's evaluated. The second time through the loop, there is nothing left to read.

Replace

```
while (my @integers = <$fh>) {
```

with

```
chomp( my @integers = <$fh> );
while (@integers) {
```

---

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
sub gcd_iter($$) {
    my ($u, $v) = @_;
    while ($v) {
    ($u, $v) = ($v, $u % $v);
    }
return abs($u);
}
my $gcdcount = 0;
my $filename = "Integers1.txt";
open (my $fh, "<", $filename) or die("Can't open file $filename, $!");
chomp( my @integers = <$fh> );
while (@integers) {
    my $value1 = shift(@integers);
    my $value2 = shift(@integers);
    my @trngpair = ($value1, $value2);
    if (gcd_iter($value1,$value2)==1) {
    $gcdcount++;
    }
}
print "$gcdcount\n";
close $fh;
```

Comment: The output is still the same with your suggestion. I'm using Strawberry Perl at the  moment. Maybe it's an issue with the compiler...?

Comment: @Kokio, Your program with my change outputs `3`, not `0`.

Comment: In hopes that image sharing is allowed within comments, here is my code: https://imgur.com/izGzAMR One compiler is giving me an output of 0 while another is giving me a blank line. I assume that I interpreted your changes wrong somehow within the code and I'd like to understand where I went wrong.

Comment: That's not the code you posted. You removed the `or die`. Please re-add that and run again.

Comment: Added and reran. Outputs don't change.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, something you've said isn't true (e.g. that's not the program you ran, that's not the data file you used, etc). Found out what ti is, and you've found your problem. Start by checking the number of elements in `@integers`.

Comment: I'm not following. I'm assuming this code SHOULD work, but it isn't.

Comment: Okay, well I'm very thankful for that. I'm using word-for-word code that should and does work on your end. Is it the compiler I'm using? I'm using both Active Perl and Strawberry Perl. I assume I will receive the correct results once I run the program on a Mac OSX or really anything different than Windows.

Comment: No, it works no matter which build of `perl` you use. There's nothing version of platform specific in that code.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to post the code? I'm a loss as to where I've gone wrong after hours of editing.

Comment: Added. Like I said, you probably aren't running the script you think you are running, or you aren't reading from the file you think you are reading. I've already suggested you start by checking the number of elements in `@integers` (e.g. using `print("num integers: ", 0+@integers, "\n");`)